# Loading CSV File in Google Colaboratory

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

HI I am using Jyputer Notebook Colaboratory

I am writing in R

How can I load the CSV File as r code

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with R, but the instructions should be relatively similar to Python.

This article is very useful: https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-load-csv-files-into-colab-7c14fcbdcb92

If none of the methods in the article suit your needs, here is another method that involves mounting your Google Drive to Collaboratory:

1. Go to Google Colab and type:

`from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')`

2. Run the code block (Ctrl + Enter), click on the link, sign in to your Google account, and copy the authorization code and paste it into the output of the code block in Google Colab.
3. The files in your Google Drive should be under the 'Files' tab when you open the left toolbar (by clicking the small arrow on the left side of the screen).
4. When you want to load the CSV in your code, enter this line of code (where loadCSV is the variable name, and the part after the = sign is the directory of the file):

`loadCSV = "gdrive/My Drive/dataset.csv"`

Answer (score 1):

I upload the spreadsheet to google drive, make it published on the web, and use the link:

```
url<-"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/AAAAAAAAAAAAA"
library(curl)

download.file(url, destfile = "./Data.csv",cacheOK=TRUE) 
Data1<-read.csv("./Data.csv",header=T,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Where the "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/AAAAAAAAAAAAA" is the weblink generated by google drive for the spreadsheet but selecting just one Sheet as csv.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
x = read.csv(filepath)
```